# Trailhead - learning path for a Java developer

Tags: trailhead

I am a fairly experienced Salesforce administrator/developer and have done numerous Trailhead modules over the past 4 years.  I want to help my brother get started with Salesforce.  He is a Java developer and has never used Salesforce.  Can you recommend a certain trail, etc. that will lead him through learning Salesforce through to developing in Salesforce?  I am overwhelmed by all the trails and not sure where to tell him to start.  We would like to have a clear path & not just jumping around.

Comment: Salesforce curated [trails](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails) should be the best way to start. You can filter based on role, level, products and tags to narrow down to a specific trail. I would recommend starting with [Developer Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner) and [Admin Beginner](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_admin_beginner) to get a fair understanding about Salesforce in general, before jumping over to other trails.

Comment: Working on the Platform Developer I trails will lead to the super badges required for Platform Developer II. Those would give a lot of hands-on experience.

Comment: I myself had been in this situation coming from a Java/J2EE background when I started my Salesforce journey & during those days, trailhead didn't exist. My approach then was to start with what is CRM (you know the offering), then map it with RDBMS concepts (you know Objects, relationships, etc.) and how I used to do build things during web development could be achieved in SF (you know config/code capabilities). With trails around this, in this sequence should be a good starting point.